# Android ANR on Draw Bitmap to Canvas

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas, bitmap, colormatrix

I apply a color effect on a `bitmap` by using a `color matrix`. Everything seems to work fine on debugging but getting this **ANR** on **production**. Here is the **code**:

```
private fun applyColorEffects(
            red: Float,
            green: Float,
            blue: Float,
            bitmap: Bitmap?
        ): Bitmap? {
            return try {
                val colorMatrix = ColorMatrix(
                    floatArrayOf(
                        red / 255.0f, 0f, 0f, 0f,0f,
                        0f, green / 255.0f, 0f, 0f, 0f,
                        0f, 0f, blue / 255.0f, 0f, 0f,
                        0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f //invert
                    )
                )
                val paint = Paint()
                paint.colorFilter = ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix)
                if (bitmap?.width != null) {
                    val finalBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                        bitmap.width,
                        bitmap.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
                    )
                    finalBitmap?.let { it1 -> Canvas(it1).drawBitmap(bitmap, 0f, 0f, paint) }
                    finalBitmap
                } else
                    bitmap
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println(e.message.toString())
                bitmap
            }
        }
```

**ANR:**

> #00  pc 00000000000f5202  /system/lib/libhwui.so
> (neon::matrix_4x5(neon::Params*, void**, float vector[4], float
> vector[4], float vector[4], float vector[4])+212)   #00  pc
> 00000000000f75a9  /system/lib/libhwui.so
> (neon::start_pipeline(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int,
> unsigned int, void**)+132)   #00  pc 00000000001001fd
> /system/lib/libhwui.so
> (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZNK16SkRasterPipeline7compileEvE3$*1NS_9allocatorIS3_EEFvjjjjEEclEOjS8_S8_S8*$2d06af249fe2b9142adef534f9f0e354+34)
> #00  pc 00000000002f36c7  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkRasterPipelineBlitter::blitRect(int, int, int, int)+198)   #00  pc
> 00000000001e6f23  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkScan::FillIRect(SkIRect
> const&, SkRegion const*, SkBlitter*)+242)   #00  pc 0000000000266d1f
> /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkDraw::drawBitmap(SkBitmap const&, SkMatrix
> const&, SkRect const*, SkPaint const&) const+602)   #00  pc
> 0000000000266615  /system/lib/libhwui.so
> (SkBitmapDevice::drawBitmap(SkBitmap const&, SkMatrix const&, SkRect
> const*, SkPaint const&)+68)   #00  pc 00000000002663f9
> /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkBitmapDevice::drawBitmapRect(SkBitmap
> const&, SkRect const*, SkRect const&, SkPaint const&,
> SkCanvas::SrcRectConstraint)+616)   #00  pc 00000000002cd3f3
> /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkBaseDevice::drawImageRect(SkImage const*,
> SkRect const*, SkRect const&, SkPaint const&,
> SkCanvas::SrcRectConstraint)+66)   #00  pc 00000000001c14bb
> /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkCanvas::onDrawImage(SkImage const*, float,
> float, SkPaint const*)+638)   #00  pc 00000000001c119f
> /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkCanvas::drawImage(SkImage const*, float,
> float, SkPaint const*)+58)   #00  pc 00000000002960f3
> /system/lib/libhwui.so
> (android::SkiaCanvas::drawBitmap(android::Bitmap&, float, float,
> SkPaint const*)+62)   #00  pc 00000000000ad57f
> /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
> (android::CanvasJNI::drawBitmap(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long long, long
> long, float, float, long long, int, int, int)+90)   at
> android.graphics.BaseCanvas.nDrawBitmap (Native method)
> at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.drawBitmap (BaseCanvas.java:115)   at
> android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap (Canvas.java:1540)   at
> com.humbbles.imagenes.utilit.Constants$Companion.applyColorEffects
> (Constants.java)   at
> com.humbbles.imagenes.utilit.Constants$Companion.createFilterList
> (Constants.java)   at
> com.humbbles.imagenes.fragments.FiltersFragment.initFilterRecycler$lambda-7
> (FiltersFragment.java)   at
> com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations$$InternalSyntheticLambda$0$d6c0ce1e0f5e72f3f1f76e60450c3292b8809a2a4ab7cdf10cff4b6c491b69e0$0.run$bridge
> (FirebaseInstallations.java)   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback
> (Handler.java:883)   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
> (Handler.java:100)   at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7626)   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)   at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
> (RuntimeInit.java:503)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
> (ZygoteInit.java:936)

Comment: Have you tried suspending the task to another thread (io)?

Comment: Not really. Can you explain it a little.

Comment: ANR can be caused when a heavy task is performed on the main thread, check `coroutines` if you are already using Kotlin for suspending tasks off the main thread.

Comment: OK thanks let me check it.

Comment: Can you show where you call this function from? By the way, your code would be simpler and make more logical sense if the input `bitmap` parameter and the return type weren't nullable.

Comment: Yeah. I'm already keeping that in check. I'm sure my bitmap is not null.